# How to merge data frames where column1 is substring of column2

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have a data frame and would like to classify each row based on the value of column df$name. For the classification I have a two-column data frame tl with a column tl$name and tl$type. I would like to merge the two data frames on a like condition, grepl( tl$name, df$name ), instead of df$name = tl$name.

I have already tried by looping over all rows in df and seeing where there is a match with tl, but this seems very timeconsuming.

E.g.:

df

```
  name        
# African elephant    
# Indian elephant    
# Silverback gorilla     
# Nile crocodile   
# White shark
```

tl

```
  name        type
# elephant    mammal
# gorilla     mammal
# crocodile   reptile
# shark       fish
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can remove the substring with `sub` by matching one or more non-white space (`\\S+`) followed by one or more white space (`\\s+`) from the start (`^`) of the string, replace it with blank (`""`) and `merge` with the second dataset ('tl')

```
merge(transform(df, name = sub("^\\S+\\s+", "", name)), tl)
#      name    type
#1 crocodile reptile
#2  elephant  mammal
#3  elephant  mammal
#4   gorilla  mammal
#5     shark    fish
```

---

If we need to update the first dataset,

```
df$type <- with(df, tl$type[match(sub("^\\S+\\s+", "", name), tl$name)])
```

Comment: Thanks. What if the substring is the start of the string, e.g. Elephant Africa?

Answer (score 1):

Another idea:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  separate(name, into = c("t", "name")) %>%
  left_join(tl)
```

Which gives:

```
#           t      name    type
#1    African  elephant  mammal
#2     Indian  elephant  mammal
#3 Silverback   gorilla  mammal
#4       Nile crocodile reptile
#5      White     shark    fish
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What would happen if there were two spaces, e.g. South American Lizard? Would the name be separated on first or second space?

Answer (score 0):

```
df

  name        
# African elephant    
# Indian elephant    
# Silverback gorilla     
# Nile crocodile   
# White shark       
tl

  name        type
# elephant    mammal
# gorilla     mammal
# crocodile   reptile
# shark       fish
```

I think this is what you want to do

```
df<-csplit(df, splitcols="name", sep=" ")
```

The above command will split that column into two columns with name.1 and name.2 column names.

```
colnames(df)<-c("name","type")
```

The above command will give proper column names for merging

```
df_tl<-merge(x=df, y=tl, by="type",all=True)
```

The above code should give you the desired output.